# Immunity from all infectious diseases?

Tags: science-based, biology, super-powers

The human body can create a quintillion variants of antibodies.
 
Resistance to infectious diseases is mainly carried out by the methods: White blood cells (white blood cells) and phagocytes.

White blood cells (white blood cells). These cells recognize and destroy foreign particles by phagocytosis (ingestion and subsequent intracellular digestion) or, in the case of large foreign bodies (e.g. parasites or large tumor cells), by isolating destructive particles by direct contact.

Phagocytosis is an important feature of the cellular link of innate immunity, which is carried out by cells called phagocytes, which “digest” foreign microorganisms or particles. Phagocytes usually circulate through the body in search of foreign materials, but can be called up to a specific location using cytokines.

My question is what needs to be improved / changed in the structure of the human body in order to improve the ability to resist infectious diseases (for example, the “bubo Plague”, Malaria, Ebola, smallpox and various viruses that mutate quickly)?

That is, it is necessary to improve the capabilities of neutralizing the body so that, for example, by inhalation, eating, etc., an infection (bacteria, viruses and various parasites) can not enter the body. For example, creating a pre-ventricle for the neutralization of food.

Also, you need to speed up / improve the creation of antibodies to destroy alien organisms in our body. (if you can do something better. Listen)

And perhaps one of the main things is that it is necessary to solve the problem of those diseases when the immune reaction itself harms our body (for example, due to a strong increase in temperature).

That is, what needs to be modified (improved) in the human body so that my genetically modified (genetic engineering) person has immunity to the most dangerous diseases?
And at the same time, so that we do not die from the reaction of the body to the disease.

Answer (score 3):

**Inherited immunity.**

The longer you walk the earth, the more diseases and antigens you encounter, and the more experienced your immune system gets.  When a baby is born it gets immunoglobulins from its mother and so for a short while can benefit from the protection of her experienced immune system.

Then after a month or two the maternal immunoglobulins wear out and baby is on its own.  The immune system starts fresh, learning to recognize and overpower the pathogens in the environment.  If it is not quick enough, the organism dies.

What if a population of T cells carrying the immune repertoire of the mother moved thru the placenta and established itself in the baby?  It is established that [white cells from one individual can take up long term residence in another](https://jcs.biologists.org/content/118/8/1559), so that aspect is not science fiction.  You would want an initial cull of T cells which generated autoantibodies but this happens in our species anyway.  You would grow up with the experienced immune repertoire of your mother.

And her mother, and her mother, and her mother.  An immune system would retain flexibility, and so if I encounter antigens new to my lineage I can generate an immune response to add (if I am female) to my ancestral defenses.  But my immune package goes way back and it is hard for any pathogen to get thru the combined might of my ancestors.

This would be a formidable adaptation and is not bizarre fiction.  The males are just along for the evolutionary ride in this scenario, which is not bizarre fiction either.

---

I did not realize this would be a GMO type solution.  The way to do this with near future tech is with something like a universal bone marrow transplant.  Currently you need to match antigens so your marrow does not reject your body (graft vs host disease).  If you could engineer white cells to not recognize and not express human alloantigens than you could use that Type O marrow for everyone.  You could transplant stem cells hacked to only produce red cells for persons with sickle cell.  If you had that tech you could engineer a repertoire of T cells that recognize all sorts of antigens and infuse them.  You will then have immunity to all those antigens and their corresponding pathogens.  You might need additional infusions from time to time depending on how well your mercenary T cells engrafted.

Comment: Humans do inherit antibodies from their mothers, passed both during intra-uterine life and through breast milk. (And if an infant is nursed by multiple women it will receive antibodies from all of them.) Search for `inherited immunity` or `congenital immunity`.

Comment: @AlexP  - Yes; and see paragraph 2.  Those antibodies do not confer lasting benefit.  Give a man a fish and he is hungry tomorrow.  Teach a man to fish and he will never be hungry.

Comment: How can this be transmitted to both sexes, through genetic engineering, and how much better (faster ) is it than the normal immune system? ( how much faster are antibodies created? )

Comment: First, I need a universal solution for both sexes ( it would be convenient if you wrote about how to achieve this ) .

 I need my genetically modified Superman to be immune to all infectious (viruses, bacteria, parasites) diseases.

In other words, I need to significantly improve the human immune system ( that is, speed up the creation of antibodies, speed up the reaction to foreign organisms, and solve the problem when the immune response is harmful to the body ( for example, due to a strong heat ))

Comment: The solution works for both sexes.  Boys and girls both have mothers.  The difference is that the experience of the males does not contribute to the ancestral heritage but males and females both inherit it.  It significantly improves the immune system because each human has an immune system that is thousands of years old and supremely skilled.  It is faster in the way an immune system experienced with a pathogen is faster than an immune system unexperienced with that pathogen.  A lot faster.

Comment: I need my genetically modified person to be completely immune to the Bubonic plague, Ebola, ( faster able to adapt to the " flu "). At the same time, facing these severe diseases for the first time.
( that is, I need to create a person who will not be killed by any infection )

Comment: silver particles are antibacterial, antiviral elements.